# How to identify whether or not a function has a definition?

Tags: function-construction, symbols

I have written a function that relies on functions from an external library that may for various reasons fail to load. I would like to test if the functions in the external library have been defined before using them.

This seems like a natural approach:

```
NameQ["unloadedFxn"] (* returns False, as expected *)
```

and in isolation it works. Unfortunately, in practice, `unloadedFxn` appears within other functions, which causes it to be initialized.

```
otherFxn[x_] := 1 + unloadedFxn[x];

NameQ["unloadedFxn"] (* returns True, which is not what I want *)
                     (* because the function still hasn't been defined *)
```

Is there some other test that would let me see whether or not `unloadedFxn` has a definition?

[Addendum: I can kludge myself to a solution with `! ToString[Definition[unloadedFxn]] == "Null"` but it feels inelegant. If you've got a cleaner solution, I'd love to hear it.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't mind using packages, then you can use `HasDefinitionsQ` from the `GeneralUtilities` package that comes with *Mathematica*:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

HasDefinitionsQ[unloadedFxn]  (* False  *)

otherFxn[x_] := 1 + unloadedFxn[x]

HasDefinitionsQ[unloadedFxn]  (* False  *)
```

Which is what you want. Now, if you give it a definition, `HasDefinitionsQ` returns `True`:

```
unloadedFxn[a_, b_] := a + b

HasDefinitionsQ[unloadedFxn]  (* True  *)
```

**Note**: You can also call the function with a `String` instead of a `Symbol` e.g.

```
HasDefinitionsQ["unloadedFxn"]
```

Comment: How did you find this? I can't find it documented anywhere.

Comment: @MichaelStern. It's not documented, I was looking for something else a few days ago in the package and accidentally stumbled on this function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how many parameters are gonna be defined you can do the following with [`ValueQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ValueQ.html) :

```
ClearAll[unloadedFxn]
otherFxn[x_] := 1 + unloadedFxn[x,y];
ValueQ[unloadedFxn[_]]
ValueQ[unloadedFxn[_, _]]
```

> False
>
> False

```
ClearAll[unloadedFxn]
unloadedFxn[a_, b_] := a+b
otherFxn[x_] := 1 + unloadedFxn[x,y];
ValueQ[unloadedFxn[_]]
ValueQ[unloadedFxn[_, _]]
```

> False
>
> True

Notice that only the second test evaluates to True since no functino is defined with one parameter in the form `unloadedFxn[_]`